# How do I apply on and off using 'and' in the middle?

Tags: prepositions

My specific example is on and off line. I am confused about how to join them without writing online and offline every time.  Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: You can say "online and off" .

Comment: I am puzzled as to why you are confused. Your first sentence does the job perfectly - *My specific example is on and off line*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [*suspended hyphen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Suspended_hyphens) to connect two words that share a base word with "and."

Wikipedia gives the example *preoperative* and *postoperative* for words that are normally written without hyphens, as your examples "online" and "offline" usually are these days.

According to their example, you should write:

> on- and offline

You should note the final statement in the paragraph, which states that some editors prefer to avoid suspended hyphens, instead writing the words in full every time. If you are writing for a publication, be sure to ask your editor what they prefer.

Comment: Thanks very much - that is what I was looking for and couldn't remember the term to ask more specifically.